# REST Spring Boot Web Service on Websphere 9

Tags: rest, spring-boot, websphere-9

I want to create a **Spring Boot REST Web Service** and deploy and publish it in **Traditional Websphere 9** Application Server. Is it possible ?
What all challenges I might encounter? Can someone please provide me few pointers for reference?

Answer (score 3):

Yes this can be done. It is not a good design, but yes it can be done. Back in the day when I was working for a big bank, they deployed java spring-boot microservices in IBM websphere(Not liberty).

**How to do it?**

1) Package your deployable as war. You can do this by editing your pom to package as WAR.

2) You can either add connection string config in your springboot starter class or get a JNDI created in the websphere instance. We observed that performance of the API's improved when the app used websphere JNDI as opposed to app created connection bean.

3) If you use IBM MQ, the best course of action is get a non-ssl and ssl based channel created at MQ and a JNDI for the MQ connection as well.

4) If you plan to create MQ connection beans within the app, like we did, ensure the JKS file has all the valid set of signers of your org.

**Problems we faced**

1) Our app used a lot of third party rule engine like drools, so ensure the websphere server.xml is configured to servlet version 3.1 or higher

2) Webshpere admin console is helpful, but don't just blindly believe if it says green to your container, always check your app logs for errors.

3) Common pain points are establishing a successful connection with IBM MQ host. Get a MQ server admin to troubleshoot all MQRC errors.

4) If you plan to use Oracle as backend, ensure the DBA has created a wallet for you to enable both SSL and Non SSL connections. Some organisations are picky with non-sssl db connections. It is easier to handle all this if you leverage webspehere JNDI for DB connections.

Let me know if this helped.

Answer (score -1):

Both WebSphere Traditional and WebSphere Liberty support Spring boot.

Are you looking for something like this?

http://www.adeveloperdiary.com/java/spring-boot/deploy-spring-boot-application-ibm-liberty-8-5/